# Silent notification working weird in iOS7 without wifi

Tags: ios, push-notification

I'm using silent notifications, which works perfectly when my phone is plugged to Xcode, using Wifi, and with a breakpoint in the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` method, when my app is in background.

My server is sending a silent notification every minutes. Here is my payload :

```
{
    aps = 
    {
        "content-available" = 1;
    };
    "update-location" = 1;
}
```

BUT, when I disable the WIFI from my phone, it doesn't receive it anymore (3g is working as usual).

I got the same behavior when I'm not plugged to Xcode.

Does anyone have a idea, or already solved it?

Comment: Is the server running on your local network by any chance?

Comment: I tried both of solutions : locally and remote (windows azure). Same behavior as well

Comment: What I think might be the problem is port forwarding on your router. I run a server locally, & I can only access it over 3G. It doesn't connect when I use the Wi-Fi of my router (even though I've enabled NAT loopback).

Comment: Forget about the local server, same behavior with remote Windows Azure's =/

Answer (score 2):

I'd do the following two things first to help me narrow down the possibilities:

1. Check what APNS gateway you're using. If you're using a distribution certificate, don't fire your notifications at the sandbox APNS URL.
2. Make sure you're using the matching provisioning profile on the device. Development profiles & distribution profiles return different UDIDs.

Also, as Viruss mca said, sometimes there's a lag from Apple's servers.

UPDATE: You've also got a semi-colon in there.

```
aps = 
{
    "content-available" = 1;
};// << Right there. It should be a comma.
```

Comment: If I had a mistake from anything of that, why does it work with WIFI and not 3g ?

Comment: @user1147981 I noticed a possible syntax error. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Solution : Add the sound key in the silent notification content....

Answer (score 1):

I guess there may two points in your case,

1. Dont send too many notifications to a device within a short span of time, coz APNS caches only 1 message/device (if the device is offline). So it can deliver the message when the device comes online. Am not sure how long the message is cached though.
2. APNS is based on Apple Servers, and Apple doesn't give any guarantee on successful message delivery.

it quite clearly in the Apple Docs that it is not 100% gauranteed and nor should it be used as so

Comment: It's very strange because if I do the following : Run my app (with 3G, and I put it in background). I send a silent notif, it didn't receive it. If I active my wifi during background, my notif is receive. You're right, it seems to be caches, but why on 3g, and not wifi ?

Comment: take some time calm, try on 3g with normal push notification, dont send continues push from server, and check is push is come or not?

Comment: I just tried something -> If I put the "sound" balise in my ['aps'] content, I receive it each time!!

Comment: Yes it's solved it. So the real question is -> Why it's sometimes working in Wifi without sound ? ...